# How to remove leading spaces or zeroes in numeric edited signed numbers in COBOL

Tags: mainframe

Please suggest the solution it will be very helpful. How I can declare the output variable and find the solution. Tried the concepts but it is not working as it is numeric edited variable.

Input variable: A pic s9(7)v99
example value: ___1644900 or ____294600
My expected output is value B = $16449.00 or $2946.00
Variable A is dynamic the value will be vary accordingly.

Comment: variable A is dynamic the amount value will vary so that time how it works

Answer (score 0):

With an output variable it is possible, then you could just add leading spaces, so it is still fixed width, but no leading zeros.

```
A-OUT     PICTURE -------9.99.
```

Alternatively the grouping separators could be used like this:

```
B-OUT     PICTURE --,---,--9.99.
```

To get rid of the leading spaces you can use the TRIM function like this:
If you declare

```
A-RESULT  PICTURE X(20).
```

To print with the `A-RESULT`

```
MOVE FUNCTION TRIM(A-OUT) TO A-RESULT
DISPLAY 'A value was $' A-RESULT
```

The output would become:

```
A value was $16449.00
B value was $2,946.00
```

There are other ways to do it, but this one is a simple approach.